# How can I disable searching in a JupyterLab cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

If I am in edit mode in a cell, JupyterLab overrides the find shortcut `Ctrl + F`. If I go into command mode, I can type `Ctrl + F` and use Chrome's find functionality.

How can I disable JupyterLab's override of the `Ctrl + F` shortcut while in edit mode, so that only Chrome's find is used?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to create a `jupyter-lab` tag. If someone could do that, it would be much appreciated, as JupyterLab is separate from (though similar to) Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Bump, I'm having this issue and it's super annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Under "Settings" > "Advanced Settings Editor", select "Keyboard Shortcuts" and in the "User Preferences" panel paste the following to disable the JupyterLab advanced document search. This will open a per-cell regex search on the first press, but a double <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will open the browser search box as requested.

```json
{
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "documentsearch:start",
            "keys": [
                "Accel F"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-mod-searchable",
            "disabled": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's no way to disable the `Ctrl + F` behavior of JupyterLab.

Instead, if you type `Ctrl + F` again in the cell search mode, you can enable Chrome's search functionality.